# Error al ejecutar script con --windowed como parámetro [PyInstaller]

Tags: python, script, pyinstaller

Tengo un error bastante raro aquí. Paso a detallarlo:

Cada vez que trato de iniciar el .exe que me genera el comando `pyinstaller --onedir --windowed -i icono.ico "Queens and Kings Egresados.py"` desde la carpeta donde se ha generado, no hay inconveniente alguno. Sin embargo, si creo un instalador con InnoSetup (incluyendo toda la carpeta generada por `--onedir`) e instalo el programa con el mismo, a la hora de correrlo me salta el error `Failed to execute script Queens and Kings Egresados`.

Según la documentación, volví a compilar el proyecto entero utilizando `pyinstaller --onedir -i icono.ico "Queens and Kings Egresados.py"` para poder visualizar en la consola el error en sí, pero increíblemente luego de instalarlo, el programa corre sin problema alguno (mostrando la consola). Claramente necesito compilar el proyecto sin la consola para poder distribuirlo.

Desde ya agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Hola Augusto, ¿si ejecutas el .exe con --windowed sin generar el instalador con InnoSetup funciona o también falla? Trata de ejecutar e exe a través de la terminal a ver si recibes algún error de salida con `cmd /K "app.exe"`. Si nada te resulta, yo trataría de generar un [log a un archivo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) con múltiples puntos control en el programa para determinar el punto en el que falla.

Comment: Hola, @FJSevilla. Si ejecuto el .exe sin generar el instalador, el programa corre perfectamente, tanto en mi computadora como en otra (que no posee Python instalado). Me he fijado si he incluido algún directorio fijo dentro del proyecto pero no es el caso. Lo que se me ha ocurrido ayer que todavía no he probado es incluir el parámetro --debug y probar el programa en su totalidad, no solo si ejecuta para ver si de esa manera puedo detectar el error. ¿Qué opinas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He descubierto cuál es error. Probé instalando el programa en otra computadora sin el parámetro `--windowed` y me ha saltado el error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Datos.bin'`. Ese archivo se debería crear la primera vez que ejecuta el programa para poder guardar los datos allí pero al no tener los permisos necesarios para "escribir" sobre esa carpeta, falla. Añadir el parámetro `--uac-admin` soluciona el incoveniente.